# How to send keys to input without losing focus?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML `<input>` field which produces autocomplete suggestions as the user types. I would like to make an automated test where the Selenium driver inputs some keys and then checks the contents of the autocomplete dropdown. The problem is that if I use the Selenium `send_keys` method, the `<input>` **loses focus and the dropdown disappears**. Is there a way to enter keys into an `<input>` element without losing the focus?

I made a minimalistic example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class TestLogin():
    def setup_method(self, method):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.vars = {}

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_minimalistic_registration(self):
        self.driver.get("https://boxing-registration.herokuapp.com/")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("email-input").send_keys("lala")
        print("done")
```

You can put a breakpoint on the last line and see that the focus of the `<input>` element is lost.

Comment: Is setting focus back to the input in question a viable solution?

Comment: @RobMoll unfortunately no. As soon as focus is lost, the autocomplete functionality is off.

Comment: After `send_keys` focus stays on input element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example app you provided, focus stays on the email input. You can check it using code below:

```
driver.get("https://boxing-registration.herokuapp.com/")
email = driver.find_element_by_id("email-input")
email.send_keys("lala")
active_element = driver.execute_script("return document.activeElement")
print(active_element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
assert active_element == email
```

You can try to use `ActionChains`, example:

```
ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element("lala").click(dropdown_list).perform()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to switch to Firefox and it worked. Switched back to Chrome and now it works on Chrome as well. Must be a bug on my side.